# Qooxdoo build-all deployment

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm new to qooxdoo. I'd like to use it for an embedded web interface for an application I'm developing right now.

To keep building my application as easy as possible I'd like to stay away from using the python build scripts after every change if possible. Because the website will only be used once in a while by a single user load times etc. are also not a big concern for me.

I've read about the "build-all" target but could not find a detailed description on how to activate it with the current release. Can someone explain how I can get a complete desktop build of qooxdoo?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to run generate.py every time you change the code, only every time you reference a new class.  During development it's usually relatively infrequent that you have to re-run the generator, compared to how often you will do the edit/save/alt-tab/refresh/test cycle.

But you can do what you're asking during development by using the "source-all" target, eg:

`./generate.py source-all`

When loading an app from a file:// url this is fine because file:// URLs are very fast, but you can optimise this manually by modifying your config.json to incorporate specific sets of classes.

To do this, in your application's config.json, add (or edit) a job called "source" and add:

```js
"jobs": {
    "source": {
      "include": [ "qx.ui.*" ]
    }
```

This will cause all of the qx.ui.* classes to be included into the `./generate.py source` build of your application; obviously you can fine tune this further.

When it comes to deploying your application, use `./generate.py build` because this will produce a minimised, optimised version (with debug code removed etc) which uses only those classes that are required.

Comment: Seems like this is not doing what I would expect. I'd like to deploy qooxdoo similar to jquery: Copy precompiled qooxdoo js/css/resources data to my application folder and add my application specific code to another file. This would skip the buildsystem completely for me except for bootstrapping as a first step. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Qooxdoo apps are compiled because you would not normally want to include everything; with jquery, you would manually select just the plugins you need.  You can do the bootstrapping with "./generate source" just once and then thats it -- unless you add more files to your code, in which case you need to re-run ./generate so that it can see your new classes

Comment: Yes, it's possible, with certain trade-off's, see @Adelise's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for a build version of Qooxdoo, here is my qxSimple project. It includes some examples.

http://adeliz.github.io/qxsimple/

You can also generate your own build version following these steps :

- Dowload the latest qooxdoo release
- Go in the **framework** folder
- Edit the **config.json** file
- uncomment the **//build-all** line
- run **generate.py build-all**

Comment: +1 @Adelise Nice work!. I like how you use `qx.core.Environment.add()` to publish the main application class, and that you cover theming. Personally, I would prefer the self-generated build as it allows keeping up with framework updates.